# "Invalid data conversion" in DB2 with prepared statements and batch

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I am using JDBC to create a temporary table, add records to it (with prepared statement and batch) and then transfer everything to another table:

```
        String createTemporaryTable = "declare global temporary table temp_table (RECORD smallint,RANDOM_INTEGER integer,RANDOM_FLOAT float,RANDOM_STRING varchar(600)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS in TEMP";

        statement.execute(createTemporaryTable);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO session.temp_table (RECORD,RANDOM_INTEGER,RANDOM_FLOAT,RANDOM_STRING) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        float f = 0.7401298f;
        Integer integer = 123456789;
        String string = "This is a string that will be inserted into the table over and over again.";

        // add however many random records you want to the temporary table
        int numberOfRecordsToInsert = 35000;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecordsToInsert; i++) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, integer);
            preparedStatement.setFloat(3, (float) f);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, string);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

        }

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();

        // transfer everything from the temporary table just created to the main table
        String transferFromTempTableToMain = "insert into main_table select * from session.temp_table";
        statement.execute(transferFromTempTableToMain);
```

This works fine up to about 30000 records in this example. However, if I were to insert say 35000 records I get the following error:

> Invalid data conversion: Requested conversion would result in a loss
>   of precision of 32768. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that field `RECORD` is a `smallint`. A `smallint` is a signed 16 bit integer with a range of -32768 to 32767.

So inserting an int value of 32768 is not allowed as it won't fit. You need to declare record as `INTEGER` instead.